# Where is the root folder of 127.0.0.1:$anyport

Tags: localhost

I can access a webpage with a local ip as for example 127.0.0.1:1234. But I can't find the root folder of this webpage. How can I know the folders location of the webpage?

Comment: Please provide information about the used webserver.

Comment: I can access it after I have installed software

Comment: I've got trouble understanding what you are saying. You must be using some sort of webserver. Apache or nginx maybe? Also what operating system are you using?

Comment: I mean i have installed poker game server on my widow 8.1 64bit pc. This include server and client. Client is web-base and to change the interface of webpage i need to access root folder of web. But i can't find that root folder.

Comment: Alright. If you can provide the exact name of the game server it may be easier to help you. Also I think these questions rather belong to http://www.superuser.com